# Como conectar uma janela do Electron NodeJS a um proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, proxy

Tenho o seguinte código em Js no node, usando o electron:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

app.on('ready', function(){
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();

  mainWindow.loadURL("https://google.com/")
})
```

ele é simples, apenas abre uma nova janela no windows com o link que esta digitado na URL. ***Eu preciso abrir este link, ou link qualquer que esteja ali, usando um servidor proxy*** configurado diretamente nas linhas do node. Fazer a conexão HTTP desta janela usando um proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para informar um parâmetro de linha de comando dentro do código, você pode utilizar o comando [app.commandLine.appendSwitch](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/command-line#commandlineappendswitchswitch-value), que reconfigura a aplicação diretamente a partir do código Javascript.

É importante que estas configurações sejam colocadas **logo no início** da aplicação, antes de instanciar a janela ou qualquer outro objeto.

Para configurar o proxy, você pode utilizar o parâmetro [proxy-server](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/command-line-switches#--proxy-serveraddressport), conforme o código abaixo:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

// AQUI => Equivalente ao parâmetro --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8080
// proxy-server = <ip do servidor proxy>:<porta>
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("proxy-server","127.0.0.1:8080");

app.on('ready', function(){
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();

  mainWindow.loadURL("https://google.com/");
});
```

Conforme o documentação, a única restrição (do [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615947), e não do Electron) é que o proxy não necessite de autenticação.

Comment: Muito bom!! Eu consegui resolver de uma outra forma, usando esta linha de comando: 

mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy({proxyRules: '127.0.0.1:8080'}); 

más a sua é muito boa também, muito obrigado. Você sabe me dizer como abrir um proxy com o node? ver todas as requisições que são feitas com o navegador e permitir ou bloquear acesso aos sites solicitados? Consegui fazer com um Framework, más não consigo dar um res.end('') usando ele e preciso de um outro método